# Proving convergence of expectation and variance given Rényi's $\alpha$-divergence tends to 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, variance, expected-value

I denote $p, q$ as density function of $P, Q$.
Given $Y, X$ are random variables and
    \begin{align}
 \int q(x)\mathbb{D}_{\alpha}[p(Y\mid X=x)\,||\,p(Y\mid x^\star)] \,dx \rightarrow 0
 \end{align}
    where $\mathbb{D}_\alpha[\cdot]$ is Rényi's $\alpha$-divergence, i.e. $D_\alpha[P||Q] = 
 \frac{1}{\alpha-1}\log\int p^\alpha(x) q^{1-\alpha}(x)\,dx$, $x^\star$ is a fix value. Can we prove $\mathbb{E}_{Q(X)}[X] \rightarrow x^\star$ and $\mathbb{V}\text{ar}_{Q(X)}[X] \rightarrow 0$?

I know (can prove) that $\mathbb{D}_{\alpha}[p\,||\,q] = 0$ iff $p=q$, but don't know how to apply it to prove the above claims.

Comment: Note that both the terms in the integral are always non-negative. If the integral goes to zero, then it implies at least one of the terms is zero. So, if you figure when should each term go to zero, you will get the answer. Also, are $X$ and $Y$ independent? If they are then I think we cannot prove that claim.

Comment: Hi, thank you. X and Y are not independent. I see that point, but is there any theorem or lemma that I can base on?

Comment: I don't think there is any specific theorem. It just follows from the fact that an integral of a non-negative function can be zero only if the function is $0$.